# Proving $\left|\cos{(x)}-1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right|\leq\frac{2}{3} \forall x\in[0,2]$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am wondering how to prove $\left|\cos{(x)}-1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right|\leq\frac{2}{3} \;\forall x\in[0,2]$.

My working so far is:
$$
\cos(x)=T_{2}(x)+R_{2}(x)\\
\text{where}\; T_{2}(x)=1-\frac{x^{2}}{2} \;\text{from Taylor series}\\
\text{and}\; R_{2}=\frac{\sin(c)}{3!}x^{3} \;\text{for}\; c\in\left(0,x\right)\subseteq\left(0,2\right)\;\text{from the Lagrange form of the remainder}\\
\implies \left|cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right|=\left|{R_{2}(x)}\right|=\left|\frac{\sin(c)}{3!}x^{3}\right|\leq\frac{2^{3}}{3!}=\frac{4}{3}
$$

I can't see how to make this bound smaller, so that it proves the original statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All odd derivatives of $\cos$ at $x=0$ are zero, therefore $T_2(x) = T_3(x)$ and

$$
 \left|\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right|=\left|{R_{3}(x)}\right|=\left|\frac{\cos(c)}{4!}x^{4}\right|\leq\frac{2^{4}}{4!}=\frac{2}{3}
$$
for $|x|\in[0,2]$.

Comment: That seems so obvious now! I completely forgot that the Taylor series for of second and third order would be the same. Thanks for the help!